# Plotly timeline with objects

Tags: python, plotly

In the below example, I would like to group the elements of y axis by continent, and to display the name of the continent at the top of each group. I can't figure out in the layout where we can set it. the example come from [this plotly page](https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/)

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly import data

df = data.gapminder()
df = df.loc[ (df.year.isin([1987, 2007]))]

countries = (
    df.loc[ (df.year.isin([2007]))]
    .sort_values(by=["pop"], ascending=True)["country"]
    .unique()
)[5:-10]

data = {"x": [], "y": [], "colors": [], "years": []}

for country in countries:
    data["x"].extend(
        [
            df.loc[(df.year == 1987) & (df.country == country)]["pop"].values[0],
            df.loc[(df.year == 2007) & (df.country == country)]["pop"].values[0],
            None,
        ]
    )
    data["y"].extend([country, country, None]),
    data["colors"].extend(["cyan", "darkblue", "white"]),
    data["years"].extend(["1987", "2007", None])

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Scatter(
            x=data["x"],
            y=data["y"],
            mode="lines",
            marker=dict(
                color="grey",
            )),
        
        go.Scatter(
            x=data["x"],
            y=data["y"],
            text=data["years"],
            mode="markers",
            marker=dict(
                color=data["colors"],
                symbol=["square","circle","circle"]*10,
                size=16
            ),
            hovertemplate="""Country: %{y} <br> Population: %{x} <br> Year: %{text} <br><extra></extra>"""
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, it is scatter plot how do you intend to group yaxis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show grouping by continent instead of the code you showed would require looping through the data structure from dictionary format to data frame. y-axis by continent by specifying a multi-index for the y-axis.
I have limited myself to the top 5 countries by continent because the large number of categorical variables on the y-axis creates a situation that is difficult to see for visualization. You can rewrite/not set here according to your needs. Furthermore, in terms of visualization, I have set the x-axis type to log format because the large discrepancies in the numbers make the visualization weaker. This is also something I added on my own and you can edit it yourself.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly import data

df = data.gapminder()
df = df.loc[(df.year.isin([1987, 2007]))]

# top5 by continent
countries = (df.loc[df.year.isin([2007])]
 .groupby(['continent',], as_index=False, sort=[True])[['country','pop']].head()['country']
)

df = df[df['country'].isin(countries.tolist())]

fig = go.Figure()

for c in df['continent'].unique():
    dff = df.query('continent == @c')
    #print(dff)
    for cc in dff['country'].unique():
        dfc = dff.query('country == @cc')
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dfc['pop'].tolist(),
                                 y=[dfc['continent'],dfc['country']],
                                 mode='lines+markers',
                                 marker=dict(
                                     color='grey',
                                 ))
                     )
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dfc['pop'].tolist(),
                                 y=[dfc['continent'],dfc['country']],
                                 text=dfc["year"],
                                 mode="markers",
                                 marker=dict(
                                     color=["cyan", "darkblue", "white"],
                                     size=16,
                                 ))
                     )
    
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, height=800, width=800, showlegend=False)
fig.update_xaxes(type='log')

fig.show()
```

[image]